# How to Fix the ‘No Space Left on Device’ Error on CENTOS 7.6

Tags: php, linux, cakephp, centos

I am using cakephp 2 and getting this error many time

```
Warning (2): session_start(): open(/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php71/sess_b6d87a5fe83ae3af3d27866faeabac35, O_RDWR) failed: No space left on device (28) [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php, line 743]
```

But my server have too much space

```
Current Disk Usage Information

Device  Size    Used    Available   Percent Used    Mount Point
    /dev/loop0  3.9G    8.4M    3.7G    1%  /tmp
    /dev/sda1   1.8T    424G    1.3T    26% /
```

I restarted server but still getting same error

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: What about quota? Did you also checked filesystem inodes limits?

Comment: @jww I know but i mentioned that server have much space. Please read my post again.  BTW i found solution, Need to set path for session in this case. Thanks

Comment: @jww Thanks i have added answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

Set session path

```
ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/tmp'));
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
session_start();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

OR 
Update session path at php.ini

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.ini
```